# Is it possible to run a shell command onto a different device?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Is it possible to run a shell command onto a different device? For example, I am writing a program in python on my computer. I want this program to call a shell command on a pi that is connected to the computer. I have the IP address of the pi, but I'm not sure if it is possible or not to do this. Does anyone know?

Comment: Invoke `ssh pi-address command`. You'll need to set up SSH keys.

Comment: @robert ... whoah you can do that? I had no idea ... do all ssh clients do that ? or is this a specific client?

Comment: OpenSSH supports keys, and if you're using shell scripts then you're probably using OpenSSH.

Comment: what robert said, generated ssh keys for each machine your using, then copy them over to the `authorized_keys` in the `.ssh` directory. If you have 2 machines, generated a key copy that into the `.ssh/authoirzed_keys`, and vice versa with the other machine or how many others your using. then by running ssh `user_name@ip_address command` will do the job. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @robert oh yeah I know how to make keys and use keys... I just didnt know you could pass a shell command into ssh ... thats awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host, port, username=username, password=password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')
print stdout.read()
```